# String Substring intentionally remove character 0

Tags: java, android, string, parsing

Im currently working on a String parsing function and suddenly i found this problem. For example:

```
String data = "1234567890JOHN F DOE";

String ID = data.substring(0,9);
String Name = data.substring(10, 19);
```

the expected output I want for ID is `"1234567890"` however
the only characters I got is only `"123456789"` and `"0"` is removed.

Are there any function I can use instead of `substring(...)`?

Comment: Change it to `String ID = data.substring(0,10);`

Comment: From [`String.substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)`'s documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,int)): "*The substring begins at the specified `beginIndex` and extends to the character at index `endIndex - 1`.*"

Comment: use String ID=data.substring(0,10)

Comment: Woaaahhh it works, i was thingking it remove the 0, thanks Man

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,int)) the `substring(...)`'s ending index is the index inputted minus one. What you want to do is have:

```
String data = "1234567890JOHN F DOE";
String ID = data.substring(0,10); 
String Name = data.substring(10, 20);
```

Output:

```
ID: 1234567890

Name: JOHN F DOE
```

Answer (score 3):

you get `"123456789"` because the end parameter in the `substring(...)` method is not inclusive, so in order to get `"1234567890"` you need to use `data.substring(0,10)` :)

Answer (score 0):

Using substring you can simply do :
str.substring (0,10);
This is another way :

```
 String pattern="\\d+";
    String text="1234567890JOHN F DOE";
    Pattern p=Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher m=p.matcher(text);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(text.substring(m.start(), m.end()));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's understand the startIndex and endIndex  you need to do this by the code :

```
String data = "1234567890JOHN F DOE";
String ID = data.substring(0,10);
String Name = data.substring(10, 20);
    System.out.println("ID:" + ID);
    System.out.println("Name: "+  Name);
```

***Output:***

```
ID: 1234567890

Name: JOHN F DOE
```

Comment: `Name` should have the value `"JOHN F DOE"`, not `"F DOE"`.

Comment: U right i have made a mistake copying and pasting from IDE!!  and the error has been corrected.